# R can not connect via RODBC to a working Teradat odbc connection

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

I am facing problems trying to connect R to Teradata via RODBC.

My system: Ubuntu 14.04; Teradata 14.10; ODBC driver 16.0; R 3.3.3; RStudio 1.0.136

I have tested the ODBC driver, and it is installed and working fine (I have tested it connecting to Teradata via SQL, using /tdxodbc64 ). I can run queries without issues.

But, when I tried to do the same in R via:

```
 library('RODBC')
 channel <- odbcConnect(dsn="MY_DSN_NAME",uid="MY_USER",pwd="MY_PASS")
```

I get this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=MY_DSN_NAME;UID=MY_USER;PWD=MY_PASS",  :
 [RODBC] ERROR: state tU, code 0, message ��������������������
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=MY_DSN_NAME;UID=MY_USER;PWD=MY_PASS",  :
 ODBC connection failed
```

If I check the datasources available in R, I get this info:

```
odbcDataSources()
LADW_V01                testdsn
"Teradata ODBC Driver"             "tdata.so"
```

Any advice will be really wellcomed!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to connect to my Teradata DW.
Works well, even in RMarkdown, and without hard-coding passwords.
Instead, it takes credentials from the Windows Database Administrator.

***NOTE:*** Code below is for *.Rmd files

`````
```{R}
# Unfortunately, odbc is not on CRAN yet
# So we will need devtools
# install.packages(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstats-db/odbc")

# Get connection info from Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator 
# Using the name you set manually
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 'Your_Data_Warehouse_Name')
```

```{sql connection = con, output.var = result}
-- This is sql code, comments need to be marked accordingly
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM My_Table
```

```{R}
# And the result is available in the next chunk!
result
````
`````

**UPDATE:** I noticed you are running Linux. I haven't yet set this up on my Linux VM, so I can't speak from experience. However, the package authors give the following [information](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc#connecting-to-a-database) on an equivalent approach on Linux systems:

> MacOS / Linux
>
> On MacOS and Linux there are two separate text files that need to be
>   edited. UnixODBC includes an command line executable odbcinst which
>   can be used to query and modify the DSN files. However these are plain
>   text files you can also edit by hand if desired.
>
> There are two different files used to setup the DSN information. -
>   odbcinst.ini - which defines driver options - odbc.ini - which defines
>   connection options
>
> The DSN configuration files can be defined globally for all users of
>   the system, often at /etc/odbc.ini or /opt/local/etc/odbc.ini, the
>   exact location depends on what option was used when compiling
>   unixODBC. odbcinst -j can be used to find the exact location.
>   Alternatively the ODBCSYSINI environment variable can be used to
>   specify the location of the configuration files. Ex. ODBCSYSINI=~/ODBC
>
> A local DSN file can also be used with the files ~/.odbc.ini and
>   ~/.odbcinst.ini.
>
> odbcinst.ini
>
> Contains driver information, particularly the name of the driver
>   library. Multiple drivers can be specified in the same file.
>
> [PostgreSQL Driver] Driver          = /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.so
>
> [SQLite Driver] Driver          = /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3odbc.dylib
>   odbc.ini
>
> Contains connection information, particularly the username, password,
>   database and host information. The Driver line corresponds to the
>   driver defined in odbcinst.ini.
>
> [PostgreSQL] Driver              = PostgreSQL Driver Database
>   = test_db Servername          = localhost UserName            = postgres Password            = password Port                = 5432
>
> [SQLite] Driver          = SQLite Driver Database=/tmp/testing See
>   also: unixODBC without the GUI for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess the problem is elsewhere, since I can connect succesfully to Teradata in the ubuntu shell, but NOT with R / RODBC nor python ... Even if I open an ubuntu shell in Rstudio I can connect without problems but not with R.

Comment: Yes, so what I am saying is use the `rstats-db/odbc` package instead of `RODBC` package :)

Comment: Here is another method in case you want to stick with RODBC: `library(RODBC); 

db <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=Teradata;DBCName=YourDB;UID=YourUserName;PWD=YourPassword"); 

Data <- sqlQuery( db, "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SOME_TABLE;"); 

odbcClose(db)`

Comment: Yes, I have tested both types of connections. The real issue here is that **I can successfully connect to Teradata via the ubuntu shell, but NOT using R or Python** (with the proper libraries in each case, and using the rigth sintax...). I guess is something "outside" R or Python, but my knowledge of Ubuntu/ODBCs is very limited.